# __add__ operator overloading does not work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, addition

So i recently learnt about operator overloading in python and tried to use it in the project i am working on. Bellow, i tried to recreate the problem i am having.

```
class Ship:
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.pos = pos
        self.center = [18, 30]
        self.leftNozzlePos = [6, 10]
        self.rightNozzlePos = [30, 10]
        self.mainNozzlePos = [18, 60]

    def __add__(p1, p2):
        x = p1[0] + p2[0]
        y = p1[1] + p2[1]
        return [x, y]

    def updateRelativePositions(self):
        self.center = self.pos + self.center
        self.leftNozzlePos = self.pos + self.leftNozzlePos
        self.rightNozzlePos = self.pos + self.rightNozzlePos
        self.leftNozzlePos = self.pos + self.mainNozzlePos

ship = Ship([600, 300])
ship.updateRelativePositions()
print(ship.mainNozzlePos)
```

So i have a bunch of position values stored in a list as `[x, y]`. I tried to overload `__add__` operator such that it returns `[p1[0]+p2[0], p1[1]+p2[1]]` with `p1` and `p1` being 2 different lists holding positions. I tried to add some position values as you can see in function `updateRelativePositions` and the result is weird. For `leftNozzlePos` and `rightNozzlePos` it prints a list of 4 items, and for `mainNozzlePos` it returns completely unchanged values. Why is this happening and how do i fix it? Thanks for any help

Comment: ` def __add__(p1, p2):` --> ` def __add__(self,other):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__add__` applies when you're adding the instances themselves (e.g. doing `ship + ship` or something); you're not, you're adding random attributes of the instances (which leads to concatenation when `list`s are involved).

The reason `mainNozzlePos` isn't changed is because you accidentally assigned it to `leftNozzlePos` (overwriting the one you computed two lines earlier).

Operator overloading doesn't make sense here, since you're not trying to support adding one `Ship` to another (what would that even mean?). You could use `numpy` arrays for your member variables, which would do element-wise addition instead of concatenation when `+` is invoked, or you could just use a simple helper method to do what you're trying to do explicitly, e.g.

```
class Ship:
    # __init__ omitted for brevity

    @staticmethod
    def _addpoints(p1, p2):
        x = p1[0] + p2[0]
        y = p1[1] + p2[1]
        return [x, y]

    def updateRelativePositions(self):
        self.center = self._addpoints(self.pos, self.center)
        self.leftNozzlePos = self._addpoints(self.pos, self.leftNozzlePos)
        self.rightNozzlePos = self._addpoints(self.pos, self.rightNozzlePos)
        self.mainNozzlePos = self._addpoints(self.pos, self.mainNozzlePos)
```

Alternatively, you could define:

```
    def _addpos(self, pt):
        pt[0] += self.pos[0]
        pt[1] += self.pos[1]
```

and avoid explicitly passing `self.pos` on every call (at the expense of making the function only add `self.pos` to things, not arbitrary points) and needing to reassign at the end, making the calls simplify to:

```
    def updateRelativePositions(self):
        self._addpos(self.center)
        self._addpos(self.leftNozzlePos)
        self._addpos(self.rightNozzlePos)
        self._addpos(self.mainNozzlePos)
```